# Assigning Int value to *Char pointer

Tags: c, pointers, types, reference, int

I'm studying pointer arithmetic, and my professor uses code like this:

```
int x = 0x01000000;
char *y = &x;
*(y+1) = 0x02;
```

to make x into 0x01020000, but even line 2 doesn't compile on my system, giving me this error: `warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'int *'`

How can I get this to run without the warning? I didn't think it would be this hard to replicate simple class material on my own computer.

Comment: what about `char *y = (char *)(&x)` ? just cast. note that you're not going to obtain the result you want on a little endian system...

Comment: note that this is "only" a warning. Your professor obviously doesn't care about them. But unless you're running on a big endian machine, with 32 bit integers you're not going to get 0x1020000 but rather 0x01000002

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre how would i ignore that warning?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: In a little-endian C implementation, one would get 0x01000200, not 0x01000002. The latter would require a “mixed-endian” implementation.

Comment: How about `char *y = (void *)&x`?

Comment: yes, you're right. @EricPostpischil. The value doesn't matter. It would just be wrong.

Comment: @JL2210 what exactly does the void do? Casting with (char *) works, but I'm wondering about the functionality of (void *)

Comment: @JohnDoe It allows casting to any pointer type. Any pointer type can be converted to `void *` and back.

Comment: @JL2210 That's cool! So (void) is a general casting tool to cast into whatever type of variable is being initialised?

Comment: @JohnDoe No, `(void *)` is. I generally use it, but it causes strict aliasing violations if you assign the pointer to any variable of type other than `char *` or the original type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to put a variable of a type into another. Since both are pointers, the compiler *can* do it, but warns you about possible undefined behaviour effects that may result from that.

If you want to ignore it, some compilers have options. `gcc` has `-Wno-incompatible-pointer-types` option for that.

But the best way is to force the cast:

```
int x = 0x01000000;
char *y = (char*)&x;
```

As a side note, it's *not guaranteed* that doing:

```
*(y+1) = 0x02;
```

turns `x` into `0x01020000`. It would do that only if 2 conditions are respected:

- machine is *big endian*
- `int` is of 32 bit size

So you see, playing with pointer casts needs you to know exactly what you're doing, else you may encounter *undefined behaviour*.